# Как целое число разбить на отдельные цифры, и вывести их через запятую?

Tags: python

например есть строка `a = 987`

как осуществить вывод в таком формате:?

```
9,8,7
```

возможно как то через цикл for() и дальше записать в список и вывести его через split с запятой, но это будет много кода, как можно реализовать покороче?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
a = 987

print( *[i for i in str(a)], sep=', ' )
```

Comment: Вместо list comprehension можно просто `*str(a)`.

Answer (score 13):

Если надо просто вывести, то, используя [ответ @S. Nick](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1213406/324059):

```py
a = 987

print(*str(a), sep=',')
#                   /\ Разделитель между элементами
#      /\ Приведение числа к строке
#     /\ Распаковка строки в отдельные символы
```

Если же строку `'9,8,7'` надо куда-то сохранить, то:

```py
a = 987

result = ','.join(str(a))
#                 /\ Приводим число к строке
#            /\ Перебираем каждый символ строки
#        /\ Объединяем через запятую
```

Результат, при необходимости, тоже можно вывести

```py
print(result)
```

Comment: Вместо /\ использовать `^` :D

Comment: Исчерпывающий ответ, хорошо )

Answer (score 0):

самое легкое, перевести в список

```
a = 987
a = list(str(a))

print(a)
```